# kdb: longList@dictionary behavior

Tags: kdb

```
q)(`a`b`c!101 0N 103)~100 101 102 103 104@`a`b`c!1 5 3
1b
```

I noticed that below two lines are equivalent

- `` 100 101 102 103 104@`a`b`c!1 5 3 ``
- `` `a`b`c!100 101 102 103 104@1 5 3 ``

1. Is it in general true that `a@b!c` is equivalent to `b!a@c`?
2. On the [overloaded glyphs page](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/overloads/#at) for `@`, is this usage `Index At` or `Apply At` or something else? For `x@y` is there documentation on the exact behavior when `y` is a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An operation that works on a list will also work on a list that just so happens to be the value of a dictionary (it applies "through" the dictionary and keeps the keys untouched). E.g.:

```
q)1+`a`b!1 2
a| 2
b| 3
q)2*`a`b!1 2
a| 2
b| 4
```

Thus an `index at` would apply the same way:

```
q)10 20 30@`a`b!1 2
a| 20
b| 30
```

since it's the same as:

```
q)10 20 30@1 2
20 30
```

1. It's not always true that `a@b!c` is equivalent to `b!a@c` if the `a@c` doesn't make sense. E.g.

```
q)10 20 30@1.1 2.2
'type
  [0]  10 20 30@1.1 2.2
               ^
q)10 20 30@`a`b!1.1 2.2
'type
  [0]  10 20 30@`a`b!1.1 2.2
               ^
```

It would only be true if the underlying datatype of the indexes is boolean/short/int/long.

2. Answered above mainly, it's `index at`. There's no explicit documentation for when y is a dictionary as it essentially is the same behaviour when y is a list